# useFormik, handlesubmit doesn't work with validationschema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, submit, formik

i try to create a form register with formik, and yup for handle error input, but when i try to submit my form nothing happen. About yup evyrthing is good it display me the errors but when i remove validationschema, handlesubmit work. I don't know why, any idead ?

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Button,
  TextField,
  Grid,
  Paper,
  AppBar,
  Typography,
  Toolbar,
  Link,
 } from "@material-ui/core";
//import axios from "axios";
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import "./auth.css";

export default function LoginFrom() {
const registerSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    firstName: Yup.string()
      .min(2, 'Too Short!')
      .max(50, 'Too Long!')
      .required('Required'),
    lastName: Yup.string()
      .min(2, 'Too Short!')
      .max(50, 'Too Long!')
      .required('Required'),
    username: Yup.string()
      .min(2, 'Too Short!')
      .max(50, 'Too Long!')
      .required('Required'),
    email: Yup.string().email('Invalid email').required('Required'),
    password: Yup.string()
      .min(2, 'Too Short!')
      .max(50, 'Too Long!')
      .required('Required'),
    passwordConfirm: Yup.string()
      .oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match')
  });
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues:{
        firstname: "",
        lastname: "",
        username: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        passwordConfirm: "",
    },
    validationSchema: registerSchema,
    onSubmit: values => {
        console.log("submited")
    }
})
const handleGoogleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open("http://localhost:5000/auth/google", "_self");
};
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div>
            <AppBar position="static" alignitems="center" color="primary">
                <Toolbar>
                    <Grid container justify="center" wrap="wrap">
                        <Grid item>
                            <Typography variant="h6">NETFLIX</Typography>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <Grid container spacing={0} justify="center" direction="row">
                <Grid item>
                    <Grid
                        container
                        direction="column"
                        justify="center"
                        spacing={2}
                        className="login-form"
                    >
                        <Paper
                            variant="elevation"
                            elevation={2}
                            className="login-background"
                        >
                            <Grid item>
                                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                                    Sign in
                                </Typography>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                                    <Grid container direction="column" spacing={2}>
                                        <Grid item>
                                            <TextField
                                                type="email"
                                                placeholder="Email"
                                                fullWidth
                                                name="email"
                                                variant="outlined"
                                                required
                                                autoFocus
                                                value={formik.values.email}
                                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                                error={formik.touched.email && Boolean(formik.errors.email)}
                                                helperText={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email}
                                            />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid item>
                                            <TextField
                                                type="text"
                                                placeholder="Username"
                                                fullWidth
                                                name="username"
                                                variant="outlined"
                                                required
                                                value={formik.values.username}
                                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                                error={formik.touched.username && Boolean(formik.errors.username)}
                                                helperText={formik.touched.username && formik.errors.username}
                                            />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid item>
                                            <TextField
                                                type="text"
                                                placeholder="Firstname"
                                                fullWidth
                                                name="firstname"
                                                variant="outlined"
                                                required
                                                value={formik.values.firstname}
                                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                                error={formik.touched.firstname && Boolean(formik.errors.firstname)}
                                                helperText={formik.touched.firstname && formik.errors.firstname}
                                            />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid item>
                                            <TextField
                                                type="text"
                                                placeholder="Lastname"
                                                fullWidth
                                                name="lastname"
                                                variant="outlined"
                                                required
                                                value={formik.values.lastname}
                                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                                error={formik.touched.lastname && Boolean(formik.errors.lastname)}
                                                helperText={formik.touched.lastname && formik.errors.lastname}
                                            />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid item>
                                            <TextField
                                                type="password"
                                                placeholder="Password"
                                                fullWidth
                                                name="password"
                                                variant="outlined"
                                                required
                                                value={formik.values.password}
                                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                                error={formik.touched.password && Boolean(formik.errors.password)}
                                                helperText={formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password}
                                            />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid item>
                                            <TextField
                                                type="password"
                                                placeholder="Password Confirm"
                                                fullWidth
                                                name="passwordConfirm"
                                                variant="outlined"
                                                required
                                                value={formik.values.passwordConfirm}
                                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                                error={formik.touched.passwordConfirm && Boolean(formik.errors.passwordConfirm)}
                                                helperText={formik.touched.passwordConfirm && formik.errors.passwordConfirm}
                                            />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid item>
                                            <Button
                                                variant="contained"
                                                color="primary"
                                                type="submit"
                                                className="button-block"
                                            >
                                                Submit
                                            </Button>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </form>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                                    Forgot Password?
                                </Link>
                                <Button
                                    variant="contained"
                                    color="primary"
                                    className="button-block"
                                    onClick={handleGoogleLogin}
                                >
                                    Login With Google
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </Paper>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

}

As i said, the yup schema works, its about validationSchema on the useFormik which give me error on the handleSubmit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error, i remove all required method on registerSchema from yup, and now it works, maybe i got error because i call required on yup AND on my textfield. Well now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see the problem is about `validationSchema` , here what you can do.

1-)
create your validationSchema simple

```
 const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    fullName: Yup.string().min(3).max(25).required(),
    lastName: Yup.string().min(3).max(45).required(),
    password: Yup.string().min(4).max(25).required(),
  });
```

## Then use the `validationSchema` in `Formik` form.

insteat of`form`

it would be like this.

```
                <Formik
                  initialValues={initialValues}
                  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                  validationSchema={validationSchema}
                >

                </Formik>
```

## Also you can use `ErrorMessage`

```
                           <ErrorMessage
                            name="fullName"
                            component="span"
                            className="erorName"
                            />
```

import like this:

```
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
```